# "Active" or "activated"?

Tags: meaning, differences, terminology

Is there a difference between an *active* state and *activated* state?

For example, if I *activate* an item, will it become *active* or *activated*? Does it depend on the context? How?

Comment: They mean different things. In the example, both apply: it becomes *active*, also, it becomes *activated* (because you activated it.) There's nothing special about the word *active*.

Comment: Can you give me an example where the difference is shown?

Comment: _this is an active verb_ ≠ _this is an activated verb_

Comment: _possums are active at night_ ≠ _possums are activated at night_

Comment: I already did. There has been an external agent (you) that did the work (activate) in the use of *activated*. With *active*, this is not relevant. HTH.

Comment: Ah, @Daniel, that is of course true!

Comment: @Kris Ah yes, that clears the abstract confusion. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most simple terms, *active* is a state, while *activated* is how it got there.

The former is a mere description of the things as they are, the latter reminds us that there was an action that had an agent. When something is activated, someone went and *made* it active.

Compare to *open* vs. *opened*.

Comment: So how is this with the example "blocked"; if blocked is how it got there then how is the state called? Or another one "verified"; if verified is how it got there then how is the state called?